# PowerShell script taking time for applying folder permissions

Tags: powershell

The following script is taking a long time to apply for folder permissions.

```
$path = 'C:\inetpub\Testbuild\folder'
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$False)
$acl | Set-Acl  -Path $path
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path
$object = New-Object System.Security.Principal.Ntaccount("BUILTIN\Administrators")
$acl.SetOwner($object)
$acl | Set-Acl -Path $path
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path
$permission = 'BUILTIN\Administrators', 'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'
$rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permission
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
$acl | Set-Acl -Path $path
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path
$permission = 'BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS', 'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'
$rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permission
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
$acl | Set-Acl -Path $path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of inheritance and propagation, setting permissions on folders with a lot of subfolders and/or items will take its time.
However, you could speed up by removing lines 13 and 14 and change line 17 to `$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)`.
That way the script won't have to set the new permissions on all underlying folders and files twice but will do it for both groups in one go.

```
# first step is to set the owner
$path = 'C:\inetpub\Testbuild\folder'
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$False)
$acl | Set-Acl  -Path $path
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path
$object = New-Object System.Security.Principal.Ntaccount("BUILTIN\Administrators")
$acl.SetOwner($object)
$acl | Set-Acl -Path $path

# next step is to set permissions for two groups
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path

# first group
$permission = 'BUILTIN\Administrators', 'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'
$rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permission
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)

# second group
$permission = 'BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS', 'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow'
$rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permission
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)

# set the permissions
$acl | Set-Acl -Path $path
```

Hope that helps